# How can i rectify the below error (Subquery returns more than 1 row) in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have five tables such as tb_rawmaterial,tb_ingredients,tb_food, tb_order_items, tb_stock.

tb_rawmaterial has all the rawmaterial for a food

tb_ingredients connects the tb_food and the tb_rawmaterial with food_id as foreign key

tb_orderitems connects the tb_foods with food_id as foreign key.

tb_stock has all the rawmaterial stock level details it connects tb_rawmaterial with material_id as foreign key.

now what i have to do is :

i have to write an update query to change the stock level when make an order for a food, i wrote the below query:

```
UPDATE tb_stock set tb_stock.quantity = (tb_stock.quantity-(
    SELECT tb_ingredients.usage_volume * sum(tb_order_item.qty)
    FROM tb_ingredients 
    INNER JOIN tb_order_item 
    ON(tb_order_item.food_id=tb_ingredients.food_id
    AND tb_order_item.order_id='ORD-T01-00289') 
    GROUP BY tb_ingredients.food_id )) 
    WHERE material_id=(SELECT tb_ingredients.material_id
    FROM tb_ingredients 
INNER JOIN tb_order_item 
ON(tb_order_item.food_id=tb_ingredients.food_id
AND tb_order_item.order_id='ORD-T01-00289')
GROUP BY tb_ingredients.food_id)
```

**BUT**

it works if the raw material data is only one, if the same raw material data repeat again it gives the below error:

**Subquery returns more than 1 row**

How can i rectify this?
Please advice me

Comment: have re-indented the SQL... in order to make it read-able.

Answer (score 1):

in order to limit the rows of the sub-queries results ...

you can either add `LIMIT 1` to the sub-query

or select by `SELECT DISTINCT`/`GROUP BY`.

using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` might also return less records.

Comment: That wont happen, it will just update the last record in the tb_stock which filter the above query!

Comment: i am not accessing the tb_rawmaterial.material_id, i just fetch the data from tb_ingredients for the process (maretial_id). the material_id is a foreign key in tb_ingredients

Comment: @VeerasingamRajeevan maybe once break that query down into individual queries and then recombine them again. those  `INNER JOIN`s look quite suspicious to me. in case you have to add `LIMIT 1` - when seeing the individual result sets, it should become pretty obvious which of the sub-queries to limit - it is one of them, for certain, because this is exactly what it complains about. without the `INNER JOIN`s, adding `LIMIT 1` is maybe not even required.

Comment: I have tried your idea but the result is same "it is just update only one row from three rows to be updated" do you have any example queries?